# Ajax return value with return not work

Tags: php, ajax

I have 2 files(call.php and post.php) and using ajax pass value from call to post,and i want to get return value from post ,but this doesn't work.   when i change post  ,modify "return" to "echo",it works,but i don't know why.can anybody give me a help?
    Examples would be most appreciated.

**call.php**

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitbt').click(function(){
    //var name = $('#name').val();
    //var dataString = "name="+name;
    var dataPass = {
            'name': $("#name").val()
        };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "post.php",        
        //data: dataString,        
        data: dataPass,//json
        success: function (data) {            
            alert(data);
            var re = $.parseJSON(data || "null");
            console.log(re);    
        }
    });
   });
});
</script>
```

**post.php:**

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    return json_encode(array('name'=>$name));
?>
```

update：

by contrast
when i use MVC "return" will fire.

```
public function delete() {
        $this->disableHeaderAndFooter();

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $token = $_POST['token'];

        if(!isset($id) || !isset($token)){
            return json_encode(array('status'=>'error','error_msg'=>'Invalid params.'));
        }

        if(!$this->checkCSRFToken($token)){
            return json_encode(array('status'=>'error','error_msg'=>'Session timeout,please refresh the page.'));
        }

        $theme = new Theme($id);        
        $theme->delete();

        return json_encode(array('status'=>'success')); 
    }



   $.post('/home/test/update',data,function(data){

                var retObj = $.parseJSON(data);

                //wangdongxu added 2013-08-02
                console.log(retObj);        

                //if(retObj.status == 'success'){
                if(retObj['status'] == 'success'){                  
                    window.location.href = "/home/ThemePage";
                }
                else{
                    $('#error_msg').text(retObj['error_msg']);
                    $('#error_msg').show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: When putting something onto the stream in PHP, use `echo`. `return` is used for functions in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, Ajax will get everything outputted to the browser.

`return` only works if you are using the returned value with another php variable or function.

In short, php and javascript can't communicate directly, they only communicate through what php echoed or printed. When using Ajax or php with javascript you should use echo/print instead of return.

---

In Fact, as far as I know, `return` in php is not even used in the global scope very often (on the script itself) it's more likely used in functions, so this function holds a value (but not necessarily outputs it) so you can use that value within php.

```
function hello(){
    return "hello";
}

$a = hello();
echo $a; // <--- this will finally output "hello", without this, the browser won't see "hello", that hello could only be used from another php function or asigned to a variable or similar.
```

---

It's working on the MVC framework because that has several layers, probably the `delete()` method is a method from the model, which returns its value to the controller, and the controller `echo` this value into the view.

Comment: I know exactly how "return" works,your answer does not match my question

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType` option in [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

```
dataType: "json"
```

In **post.php** try this,

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo json_encode(array('name'=>$name));// echo your json
    return;// then return
?>
```

Comment: when adding Use this option in $.ajax()

dataType: "json" ,still not work

Comment: @wusuopubupt did you get `data` in `alert`?

Comment: Then check in `console`, your `ajax request` for `post.php` is called or not.

Comment: You guys are totally missing the point, the ajax / jquery part is fine. You just don't have to use "return" in those cases. Dunno who upvoted that